# How to select a column that shows sum of all previous column and current column in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table tblTransaction with column paidAmount,paymentDate, and transactionId.
I want to select a column that contains all previous row's paidAmount and current row's paidAmount as ClosingBalance.

This is what i want to achieve [image]

Comment: Keyword: *running total*

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.paidAmount, a.transactionId,a.paymentDate, (SELECT SUM(b.paidAmount)
                       FROM tblTransaction b
                       WHERE b.transactionId <= a.transactionId)
FROM   tblTransaction a
ORDER BY a.transactionId;
```

Comment: when i try to filter data by payment date it shows wrong value

Comment: Can you post the query?

Comment: SELECT TR.paidAmount,TR.transactionId,TR.paymentDate,TR.createdDate,TR.paymentMode,TR.transactionType,
SUM(CASE WHEN TR1.transactionType='SALARY' THEN -TR1.paidAmount WHEN TR1.transactionType='FEES' THEN TR1.paidAmount END)ClosingBalance
FROM tblTransaction TR LEFT JOIN tblTransaction TR1 ON TR1.transactionId<=TR.transactionId 
 WHERE TR.paymentStatus='A' AND
  TR.sessionId=1 AND TR.paymentDate='09/09/2015'
GROUP BY TR.paidAmount,TR.transactionId,TR.paymentDate,TR.createdDate,TR.paymentMode,TR.transactionType
 ORDER BY TR.transactionId DESC